# Can we deploy a C# 7 web app to Azure using Kudu?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

Since Visual Studio 2017 is released and we can use the new C# 7 features I expected this will work when deploying on Azure Web apps.

Unfortunately we're seeing compile errors when using continuous deployment (kudu git deploy) so it seems Azure doesn't support the new toolchain yet.

Is there anything we can do to get this to work now (besides publishing the assemblies directly)?

Comment: Are you using a local version of Kudu?

Comment: No, we're simply commiting to Github, which triggers Azure to fetch the changes using Kudu.

Comment: Oh, I wonder if they haven't updated to the latest build tools on Azure yet. Can you tell what version of MSBuild is running from the logs?

Comment: Yes, it's running version 14.0. And I've checked the folder (`D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild`), it doesn't contain a newer version.

Comment: Can you please [share a minimal repro repo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue)? In our tests this was working as the compilers are coming from a NuGet package.

Comment: What's the package? I'll check to see if we have it. This is a solution that was created in VS2015, later opened in '17 where some C# 7 code was added. Locally it builds in '17, but not '15.

Comment: Adding the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` NuGet package fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You try to help then the guy who writes the product comes along and gazumps you! :) I suggest adding that as an answer btw, it might help future people.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

since we don't yet have msbuild15 in Azure.
if you want to use c#7 features with continuous integration, you may need some workaround

1. for **dotnet core web solution**, you can build it in Azure **out of the box**. (it uses its own `dotnet msbuild.dll`) [[repository sample](https://github.com/watashiSHUN/AspNetCoreC-7webapi/blob/master/netFrameworkTest/Controllers/ValuesController.cs#L23)]
2. for **asp.net web solution**, you need to add `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` 2.0+ nuget package to the **project where the new language feature is applied**. For example, if a class library in the solution is using the new syntax, you need to add nuget package to that lib project. (the new c# compiler is thus imported if you refer this nuget package) [[repository sample](https://github.com/watashiSHUN/webappCsharp7Lib/blob/master/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.csproj#L3)]
3. finally for **mixed solution (dotnet core web app + .NET framework class lib)**, you need to run `nuget restore` for the .NET framework lib project **independently** since `dotnet restore` is not backwards compatible, it cannot retore project from the old build system. I did this by hacking my `deploy.cmd` [[repository sample](https://github.com/watashiSHUN/CoreAndFrameworkProj/blob/azure-hack/deploy.cmd#L69-L74)]

these workarounds either try to
imitate msbuild15 (case1: `dotnet msbuild.dll`, case2: compiler as a nuget package)
or imitate nuget4.0 (case 3: run both `dotnet restore` and `nuget3.5 restore`)

we are in the process of building these tools for Azure, they should be out soon. you can stay updated on [github](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2350)

Comment: Adding Microsoft.Net.Compilers solves the problem... but slows down dramatically the builds!! It's frustrating :(

Comment: @Subgurim msbuild-15.3-preview is already in Azure west us2, this building tools will soon be available everywhere

Comment: Great! I wish it would be announced properly ;)

Comment: Scenario #2 works for me with Microsoft.Net.Compilers v2.4.0, but not v2.6.0 (I still see an error about lack of MSBuild 15).

Comment: My deployments are failing because MSBuild is being detected as v14 instead of v15.  The error is releated to using the <PackageReference> element in the project file `Error MSB4066: The attribute "Version" in element <PackageReference> is unrecognized`

Comment: @joshuanapoli Thanks for the tip. Spent about 3 hours trying to get Kudu to deploy my app today; I downgraded Microsoft.Net.Compilers v.2.10.0 to 2.4.0 and it succeeded. watashiSHUN - any idea why it's necessary to downgrade this nuget package to get this to work on a brand new azure app service plan to get kudu to build a .net 4.7 using c# 7 tuples?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` NuGet package fixes the issue.

Comment: "[You need to install Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.0+ nupkg in order to support C# 7.0 features.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216740/c-sharp-7-features-dont-work-within-a-web-project-on-visual-studio-2017-rc)"

Comment: @watashiSHUN That's not the same thing. c# 7 features worked without issue in VS2017, only when deploying a problem occurred.

Comment: This is not working for me if deploying from deployment from github

Comment: What's the error message? We're also deploying from Github and this fixed it for me.

Comment: For "classic .NET" (in my case targeting .NET 4.5) adding `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` seems to do the trick – but please note that ALL projects that use C# 7 syntax need to have the package added, adding it to the web project only is not enough

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @joshuanapoli in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071785/can-we-deploy-a-c-sharp-7-web-app-to-azure-using-kudu#comment-82600852) to the accepted answer **Scenario #2 works only with Microsoft.Net.Compilers v2.4.0 and below.**

Took me a couple of hours to notice and figure it out.